# Show image in fabrik (joomla)?

Tags: css, image, joomla

I'm creating a new website using JOOMLA and for the database am using fabrik. I need to show the image on the form from the database.

Answer (score 0):

"**The 'file upload' element is what you need to upload files with. However, we don't currently support storing uploaded files in the database, we store them in the file system (or in Amazon S3 storage).**"

This is as per the official fabrik forum http://fabrikar.com/forums/index.php?threads/upload-image.17401/

So I dont think you can save images to DB and rather save it on the file system and refer it in your application

Comment: Well your answer did solve some of my queries, I have already stored the image in a file system but retrieving image path is the issue! If I provide static image path to the show image from image plugin it works, but if I provide PHP code for showing dynamic image on the basis of a particular id it isn't working!

Comment: Please post relevant HTML getting generated. In the web page, you can right click on the place where you expect the image to be loaded and select inspect page to see the HTML. See if the image tag is broken.